# Using a laptop as a bridge between Internet and LAN for SSH connections.

Tags: ssh, bridge

We have a lan and a server running HPUX that isn't connected to the Internet.

I have a server and a laptop on the same network. When I plug in the laptop via ethernet cable, its Internet connection drops, despite already being connected via wifi to a network with Internet access.  From the laptop, I can only SSH to the server using its internal IP address.( 192.168...)

What I wonder is, can I connect to the server from somewhere else in the world via the laptop? How can I make the laptop act as a bridge between the Internet and the LAN? How would I then access the server?

Comment: What distribution is the laptop running? How is the network configured?

Comment: It may be a windows laptop or a raspberry pi running raspbian

Comment: If it's a Windows laptop, the question is off-topic. For the Raspbian case, are you using NetworkManager? Post the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy, I guess you have to configure a VPN form the laptop to your endpoint using as peer you public IP address and host your laptop private IP address, also configure the laptop with a specific software such as ha-proxy or even IPTABLES talking about Linux environment. Then aim all traffic you want to the server.